# IIS 7.5 Compression & Chunked Transfer Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, http-compression, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

I had to render a json feed. Since the size of the feed is around 10 MB, I decided to enable compression in ASPNET. I enabled dynamic compression for json mime type. Compression works well and reduced the size to 1 MB (significant compression benefit for server CPU utilized).

But wierdly, the browser took 2.6 mins each time and failed though I see JSON received in few seconds.

I tried to debug with fiddler and inspection tools. I see chunked transfer encoding in response. So the browser waits for about 150 seconds to receive 0 sized chunk to complete.

I don't flush response in any of the json service. So IIS enables chunked transfer in this case. Turning off enableChunkedEncoding didn't help either.

How do I get this compression working or compression + chunked transfer work together?

Here are the request and response headers.

**Request Headers**

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/Default2.aspx

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200 OK

Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch

**Response Headers**

Content-Encoding:gzip

Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8

Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Edited:
Interestingly, everything works fine when compressed response is < 1 MB. Issue creeps in when response is > 1 MB. I created test project [here](https://github.com/lokeshwer/HttpChunkedTest)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Do you set the size on header at any time ?

Comment: No. I didn't. I created a test project https://github.com/lokeshwer/HttpChunkedTest